# How to call the Sub () in specific cell?

Tags: excel

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbUI.jpg)

I want this code to call in Cell A20, my question is how to call this Sub() ? thanks

```
Sub N323100z()
Dim x As String, rcell As Range, y As String, z As Long
x = "T" & Format(Now, "mmddyyhhnnss")
y = Left(x, 10)
z = Right(x, 2)
For Each rcell In Range("D21:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row)
If Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = "" Then Cells(rcell.Row, 1) = y & z
z = z + 1
Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a button and assigning it this macro?

Comment: Yes I did but I have a problem because this code is for generating unique ID for each task. Everyday we received a task in one of the shared worksheet so the so the information in Row 21 will move to Row 22 if there is a new task assigned. Problem is the previous ID doesn't  move downwards with its specific Row, the ID stuck in Row21. any inputs on how to create a code so every time there is a new task the ID will also move downwards?

Comment: I attached the image for reference. thank you

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you need.